# Xpath Contains with Regex pattern

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, groovy

```
def xpath ="//span[contains(text(),'0')]"
```

with the above XPath, the text contains only numbers and this is dynamic. is it possible to apply the regex pattern in the above Xpath?

regEx pattern :`^[0-9]`

```
def myXpath = //span[contains(text(),'^[0-9]')]'
testObject.addProperty('xpath',ConditionType.EQUALS,myXpath)
def action = WebUI.getText(testObject)
```

I'm getting the below error

```
Web element with id: 'objectName' located by '//span[contains(text(),'^[0-9]')]' not found (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'objectName' located by '//span[contains(text(),'^[0-9]')]' not found
```

Let me know how can I apply the regex pattern in XPath?

Comment: Do you realize that `contains(..., 0)` would match for 0 anywhere in the string while the regex `^[0-9]` would require the first character to be a digit? Could it be that there just isn't any such object? (I'm not a XPath expert though)

Comment: @Thomas yes that contains digits may be (0145 or 0101 or 0200 etc.,)

Comment: There seems to be a `matches()` function, did you try that?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I tried with matches() but received the same error "def xpath = "//span[contains(text(),matches(.,'[0-9]')]"

Comment: I'd have assumed that you'd need to do it like `//span[matches(text(),'^[0-9]')]"`

Comment: @Thomas getting the same error

Comment: Share HTML sample

Answer (score 1):

Selenium unfortunately only supports the very old XPath 1.0 standard, which has no support for regular expressions. Regular expression support came with XPath 2.0 but Selenium has yet to upgrade.

It's sometimes possible to devise workarounds using `translate()`, for example `translate(x, '0123456789', '')=x` is true if x contains no digits. (But I'm not sure what condition you're actually trying to test for, since you haven't stated the precise requirement, you've only shown us code that doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select element with number as text you can use workaround

```
//span[number(.) >= 0]
```